# How do you integrate gradle and jboss 6 to generate working eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, jboss, gradle

**The situation**

I want to integrate a gradle script to specify the dependencies for JBoss AS 6 and use that script to create eclipse projects.  We are currently using gradle for a project.  It builds fine, and runs tests correctly, but when we try to import it into eclipse, we get errors.  We have a *property* variable called *jbossHome*.  I dumped all of the libs into one directory for jboss6 and that is what *jbossHome* points to.

```
repositories{
    fileTree(dir: jbossHome)  //include required JBoss jars
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile fileTree(dir: jbossHome)  // include the required JBoss jars    
}
```

**The problem**

When we import into Eclipse, we get the following errors:

- Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
- Target runtime jboss-6.0.0.Final Runtime is not defined.

We have both a web service project and a jms project that we need to set this up for.

**Question #1**
 - How can I setup my project to use the maven repo and include/exclude the correct jars similar to this [jboss 7 example](https://github.com/pgier/jboss-as/blob/gradle/build.gradle)?

**Question #2**
 - If using the Maven repos, is there a way to specify it to cache it to a specific directory so it doesn't download every time for integration into a CI server like Jenkins?

Note:  I have been jumping around projects and languages, and I am not that familiar with Gradle or Maven.  I am pretty familiar with CMake, but AFAIK there isn't a similar concept with dependencies and maven repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gradle worked for me.  I was also trying to deploy via war so I needed to make sure that I used *providedCompile* instead of *compile* otherwise every jboss .jar file ended up in the war file.

```
repositories {    

   mavenCentral()
   mavenRepo urls: "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"

}


dependencies {
   //*****Note - providedCompile means to use it during compile, but don't include the war

   //jboss and hornetq 
   providedCompile ("org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-client:6.0.0.Final") { 
      exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-annotations'  //error if not excluded
      exclude group: 'com.sun.istack', module: 'istack-commons-runtime'  //error if not excluded

   }
   providedCompile ("org.hornetq:hornetq-jms:2.1.2.Final")


}
```

I hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Note:  There seems to be a bug in deeply nested dependency resolution in Gradle.  We are moving back to the file/dir based method.

Comment: Note # 2, this only seems to work with non-dynamic web projects.