# How to resolve dependencies from Java EE container (JBoss)

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, gradle

I am new to build tools and now developing a web application using Spring 4.0.6 and Gradle.

When running *gradle build*, I got a errors saying that javax.persistence and javax.servlet cannot be resolved:

> package javax.persistence does not exist
>   package javax.servlet does not exist

How can I tell Gradle to resolve Java EE dependencies from the container? I don't want to add a dependency in my project and then have JARs like hibernate and servlet-api bundled in my WAR file. I want to get them from the container, which is the main purpose of a Java EE container...

My *build.gradle* file:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {

    maven {
        url "file://my_internal_maven_repo_server/maven2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.0.2.RELEASE'

    compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2.1.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:2.1.3.RELEASE'
}
```

My specifications:

- IDE: Eclipse Juno.
- Java EE container: JBoss AS 7.2
- Application format: WAR (desired build structure [here](http://www.jmdoudoux.fr/java/dej/images/ejb31002.png))

Thank you

Charles

Comment: While it is once to have those jars in the JBOSS subsystem it is not the primary purpose of the container. There are many containers in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that you should use providedCompile to exclude them from the war.

Please see: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/war_plugin.html and

http://gesellix.net/providedcompile-and-compile-dependencies-with-gradle/

For example:

```
providedCompile ("org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-client:6.0.0.Final")
```

per [How do you integrate gradle and jboss 6 to generate working eclipse projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956699/how-do-you-integrate-gradle-and-jboss-6-to-generate-working-eclipse-projects)